# ANDROID_HOME won't set and Cordova projects don't build

Tags: linux, cordova, variables, environment

Everything was working perfectly last month, my Cordova projects were building with no problems but suddenly nothing works. Not even the Cordova Hello World example.
I can create a Cordova project.
But when I try to build it I get errors.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. When I try build a project with

```
cordova build
```

I get a whole bunch of acces errors

> rm: could not remove file (code EACCES):
>   and

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied
```

then when I try to build a project with sudo I get the following errors

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
```

and

```
Command failed with exit code 2. You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

Running export in terminal doesn't solve the problem either as my android-sdk is installed in a folder called Software/android-sdk-linux and

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

returns the correct path
Any idea whats actually going on here. Do I really need to uninstall everything and start from scratch? say it aint so!

Comment: Are you signed in as a user with access to that path? You might want to check the permissions on your project and the `android-sdk-linux` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on that issue for the last two hours. Somehow I managed to make it work. Here's what I did:

1. I also had those `Error: EACCES, permission denied` messages when running `cordova build`. Running `ll` on the directory of the project showed, that the folders *platforms*, *plugins* and *www* needed **root** rights. That's why we had to run the `cordova build` with **sudo**. Maybe both, you and me, created this cordova project with `sudo cordova create ...`. Try this: Create another cordova project and check if the named folders still need root rights. If yes, change them with `chmod`. If not, you should now be able to run `cordova build` without **sudo**.
2. Make sure you added the PATH variable in the correct way. Either add the `export ANDROID_HOME=...` to your `~/.bashrc` or to your `~/.profile`. When doing the latter, make sure you run `source ~/.profile` after editing the file. Otherwise your bash won't notice the changes. Best practise would be adding this to your `~/.bashrc`.

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=~/.../android-sdk-linux
   export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
   export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
   ```
3. You should be able to run `android` in your bash, before trying to build a cordova project, because cordova uses that command.

Hope that works for you, too.